# remove escape characacter from the reponse of webapi

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Hi i have a controller to return translations:

```
 [HttpGet("/api/getpublictranslations")]
    public async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> Getpublictranslations([FromQuery(Name = "locale")] string locale
    {
        try
        {
            return await _translationBusiness.GetPublicTranslation(locale);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

when i test my api i have some escape character on the reponse of api normally `\n` and not `\\n`
[image]

because on db i have:
[image]

do you know how can i delete this escape character from reponse?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to completely remove these characters try this :
`.Replace(" \\n", "")`
if you want to keep "end line" character try this :
`.Replace("\\n", "\n")`

Comment: no i must return \n and it's not a caracter it's an escape added to the string

Comment: the second option I denoted, would do what you need.